# Run an xslt on xml files from various folders

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xslt that I need to run on multiple xml files that are present in a folder 'source' he hierarchy of the files is as follows:

**file 1**: source/a/1.xml
**file 2**: source/b/2.xml
**file 3**: source/b/3.xml
**file 4**: source/c/4.xml

and so on. How do I run the following xslt on these xml files

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="collection( 'source//*.xib')">
        <xsl:variable name="filename" select="document-uri(.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="filename1">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($filename,'source/')"/>
        </xsl:variable>         
            <xsl:result-document href="res/{$filename1}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:result-document>              
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell us which XSLT processor you are using. The URIs recognized by the XSLT 2.0 `collection()` function are processor-dependent. In addition, you haven't said whether there are other files in this directory structure that you DON'T want to process.

In Saxon, if you want to process all the XML files in a directory you can use

```
collection('source?recurse=yes;select=*.xml')
```

Comment: The XSLT processor I'm using is XMLSpy and there are other files in this folder structure that i don't want to process

Comment: Then you'll have to consult the RaptorXML documentation. I don't expect Altova are listening to this forum (but you never know...)

Comment: Thanks, but decided to go another way and use powershell to accomplish this. Very simple 5 line code to achieve it.

Comment: Yes, when the transformations to be applied to each file are completely independent of each other, then controlling it externally to the XSLT code is often the best way.